# Fedora OS Sound Not Playing Through Projector Via HDMI Cable

Tags: fedora, audio, display

The sound does not play through a connected projector with speakers via HDMI cable. Instead the sound plays on the computer speakers, video does display on projector however.

I have an HP Sleekbook 15 running Fedora 25.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the Windows (Overview) button and type "sound" — hit the down arrow and bring up the Sound settings applet. (Or, pick it from the menu — bring down the menu on the top right, and click the tools icon, and then run the Sound applet from there.)

You'll see a dialog like this:

[image]

but *unlike* mine, you should see an HDMI output also listed. (I don't, currently, have one available to demonstrate with.) Click that that to change the output, and the sound should be redirected.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on why this doesn't happen automatically; I'll check with some of the desktop developers after the holidays.